# Warning: Failed prop type: Game: prop type `game` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from React.PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

// import UI components
import GameList from '../components/game/GameList';

// import actions
import gameActions from '../actions/game';

const Game = (props) => {
  const { game, actions } = props;
  return (
    <GameList game={game} actions={actions} />
  );
};

Game.propTypes = {
  game: PropTypes.shape.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.shape.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    game: state.game,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(gameActions, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Game);
```

I am trying to pass these two props as objects to a component and I am getting the invalid prop type error.

I need these two props to be objects, and I am pretty sure they are objects, why it needs them to be function?

Comment: can you plz share the exact error messages based on this code? Currently i am not able to understand ur question.

Comment: lol, sorry , the question title is exact the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies in your propTypes definition:

```
Game.propTypes = {
  game: PropTypes.shape.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.shape.isRequired,
};
```

for each you should be doing: `PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired` or `PropTypes.object.isRequired`

by just doing `shape` it's passing the shape function as the expectation.